# How do I delete a new Admin account and its data without knowing the old admin password?

Tags: mojave, macos, administrator

I used my friend's Mac by creating a new admin account.  Now I need to return it and want to delete the new Admin account I created without knowing his password.  In other words, can I delete my own Admin account?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) `I used my friend's Mac by creating a new admin account.` How did you create the account? What harm is in asking your friend to delete the account when you return the Mac?

Comment: Yes: How did you create a new admin account without knowing the existing admin password?

Comment: I used this process:  Hold ⌘ + S on startup.
mount -uw / ( fsck -fy is not needed)
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone.
reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, create a new Admin user account as your account allows to make it.
2. Login with the new admin account.
3. Delete your original account and select the "Delete home folder" option.

Easy way to delete your account with settings, not so easy to delete the new second account but your friend can do that with their admin account (hopefully)

Comment: ... and you are left with another new admin (with less data though) :-(

Comment: I agree but that wouldn't hamper either way. At least he doesn't need to panic with his data. His friend can remove newly created admin account later.

Comment: Thank you again. . . That’s what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to follow this : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Comment: Do *NOT* follow those instructions in this situation. That procedure is to remove the primary user's Internet accounts from a computer and erase it. In this case, we don't want to disturb the primary user at all, just remove a temporary extra local user.

Comment: It is clearly advised to follow these procedures when you give away a Mac. Just removing an account will not remove /System and /Library datas that could have been soft-linked to your user/apple id/internet accounts.

Comment: This isn't a case of giving away a Mac. The Mac is being *returned* to its owner and primary user, whose files, accounts, etc are all on the computer and *should not be deleted*.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought the primary user removed all of his datas.

Comment: Yes, first of all thank you so much for the imput, @GordonDavisson is correct. I sublet my friend's apt and he never really gave me permission to use it.  I thought I would be able to delete my new account without touching his just like I was able to create it so he doesn't panic thinking I went through his password-protected files.  I was reading that technically an admin can get access to another admin's files and I don't want him to think that's what I did.